# getElementById + variable controlling another getElementById + variable

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I have different divs, each of them having a button calling the same function.

```
<div id="div1">. . .</div>
<button id="btn1" > INIT </button>
<div  id="div2">. . .</div>
<button id="btn2"> INIT </button>
```

Tricky part is that each button should only execute the function to his own div (`#btn1` to `#div1`, `#btn2` to `#div2`, etc) and not to the others. The code I wrote executes the same function to every div without me clicking a button. I guess the answer is easy but I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var b = 1;

for (var b = 1; b < 5 ; b++) {
    document.getElementById("btn" + b).onclick = 
    document.getElementById("div" + b).innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD";
}
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/balleronde/tr8wntmL/

How can I execute the function to `#div1` only when clicking `#btn1`, and not to all at once ?
thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById("btn" + b).onclick = 
    document.getElementById("div" + b).innerHTML` ? O.o

Comment: what do you actually want?  you set innerhtml of each div same as a result of this all looks this.

Comment: Have a look at the updated fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/tr8wntmL/1/

Comment: I'm trying to set id's dynamically so that #btn1 will insert "hello world" into #div1, #btn2 to #div2, etc. That's what I tried to do with "btn"+b and "div"+b. This would prevent me from copying the same function hundred of times in my code

Comment: @Nora, check my answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick and simple answers ! You two made my day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
document.getElementById("btn" + b).onclick = 
document.getElementById("div" + b).innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD"
```

As far as JavaScript knows, that looks like this to it:

```
x = y = "HELLO WORLD"
```

Here's what happens when you do that:

```js
x =
y = "hello world"

console.log("x is:", x)
console.log("y is:", y)
```

So your code ends up setting the `innerHTML` property of `#div(b)` *and* the `onclick` property of `#btn(b)`! Whoops, that's not what you want.

What you really want is for `#div(b)`'s `innerHTML` to be set when you click on `#btn(b)`.

To do that, you need to assign a *function*, or a *callback*, to `#btn(b)`'s `onclick` property:

```js
function setTheText(b) {
  document.getElementById('div' + b).innerHTML = 'HELLO WORLD'
}

for (var b = 1; b < 5; b++) {
  document.getElementById('btn' + b).onclick = function() {
    setTheText(b)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>Div 1</div>
<div id='div2'>Div 2</div>
<div id='div3'>Div 3</div>
<div id='div4'>Div 4</div>
<button id='btn1'>Button 1</button>
<button id='btn2'>Button 2</button>
<button id='btn3'>Button 3</button>
<button id='btn4'>Button 4</button>
```

Hmm.. we get an error when we click on the buttons: "Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot set property `innerHTML` of `null`". Whoops!

Let's investigate. Here's what happens when we replace the `setTheText` function's code with something that logs `b`:

```js
function setTheText(b) {
  console.log(b)
}

for (var b = 1; b < 5; b++) {
  document.getElementById('btn' + b).onclick = function() {
    setTheText(b)
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='btn1'>Button 1</button>
<button id='btn2'>Button 2</button>
<button id='btn3'>Button 3</button>
<button id='btn4'>Button 4</button>
```

It always outputs 5! That doesn't make much sense.

Basically the issue is `b` gets changed to `5` by the `for` loop before JavaScript calls your `onclick` function.

So what we really need to do is use a function to *create* the callback function, so that the callback function can remember what index (`b`) it was created with:

```js
function makeSetTheText(b) {
  function setTheText() {
    document.getElementById('div' + b).innerHTML = 'HELLO WORLD'
  }
  return setTheText
}

for (var b = 1; b < 5; b++) {
  document.getElementById('btn' + b).onclick = makeSetTheText(b)
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>Div 1</div>
<div id='div2'>Div 2</div>
<div id='div3'>Div 3</div>
<div id='div4'>Div 4</div>
<button id='btn1'>Button 1</button>
<button id='btn2'>Button 2</button>
<button id='btn3'>Button 3</button>
<button id='btn4'>Button 4</button>
```

It that's still a bit confusing, don't worry, there's a bunch of really good explanations on how closures and functions that generate functions on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

If you've made it this far, hopefully:

1. You'll have learned a bit about debugging.
2. You'll have figured out a solution to your problem.
3. You'll have learned a couple fancy JavaScript tricks.
4. You'll have some sympathy for the amount of lag I had to deal with while typing this answer, and all the research and testing I did.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want something like this:

Create function-handler with parameter

```
function myAwesomeHandler(param){
   document.getElementById("div" + param).innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD";
};
```

Bind this handler, so you handler will be called with counter value as parameter. Check documentation about [**bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
for (var b = 1; b < 5 ; b++) {
    document.getElementById("btn" + b).onclick = myAwesomeHandler.bind(this, b);
}
```

Although there are more elegant ways with different html, I assumed you have predefined html structure and just demonstrated "only js" method.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<div id="div1">. . .</div>
<button id="btn1" onclick="changeText('div1')"> INIT </button>
<div  id="div2">. . .</div>
<button id="btn2" onclick="changeText('div2')"> INIT </button>
```

and create a function,

```
function changeText(divId){
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = 'some text';
    }
```